# Have anybody an useful implementation of rowClone, blockClone from phpWord (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)?

Tags: php, github, phpword

Currently I'm having problems with rowClone and blockClone specially. In the documentation they says that if we use rowClone over a table with merged cells, the function (rowClone) will clone the adjacents rows, so I said, ok well, it looks pretty nice. So I made a table as you can see in the image 1, but when I execute the script, the function rowClone doesn't work as I was expecting. 
Then reading the documentation deeper, I realized that there is another function called blockClone, but when I tried to use it, surprise, it doesn't work neither.

Finally I started looking for solutions on the Internet, but nothing they proposes help me, so please if you have any advice, hack, anything, please comment. Thanks in advance.

[Image 1: template (.docx)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1VRE.png)

[Image 2: result after processing the template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D8GG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug in the source code. There is a space in a regular expression that made function preg_match does not match anything. Following I show you how to fix it:

This is the original code:

```
 if (!preg_match('#<w:vMerge/>#', $tmpXmlRow) &&
                    !preg_match('#<w:vMerge w:val="continue" />#', $tmpXmlRow)) {
      break;
}
```

And this te code fixed.

```
if (!preg_match('#<w:vMerge/>#', $tmpXmlRow) &&
                !preg_match('#<w:vMerge w:val="continue"/>#', $tmpXmlRow)) {
            break;
}
```

The above if is between 298 and 302 in the source code (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/TemplateProcessor.php)

I have hope it could help you!